# P2Pool Payout Addresses vs Worker Addresses

Tags: wallet, address, nodes, p2pool, dash

I initially did a setup of 3 Antminer D3's following [DIRECTIONS AT THIS LINK.](https://dashpay.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/155746344/How+to+set+up+a+Dash+P2Pool+node)

I used a payout address for my P2Pool command line that I created in my Dash Core wallet. I did NOT initially use wallet receipt addresses for each of my miner's worker names, but instead called them DASH01, DASH02, DASH03.

As I continued to research, seeking to find ways to optimize my mining and my miners on my P2Pool, I learned to set the difficulty using address+diffnumber. That led me to realize that the REASON I was NOT seeing complete stats for my miners on my P2Pool monitoring web pages, was because I was not using wallet reception addresses generated by my wallet/node for my worker names.

Now that each worker has a separate wallet/node receiving address, I can see all the stats.

Herein lies my question. Should none of my worker addresses use the same address as my payout address? I am confused about this particular point. Thanks for clearing up any conceptual errors too.

Comment: It occurred to me that IF I have wallet reception addresses for my worker names = address+diff, I don't need a payout address in my p2pool command line - is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and experience, I can now answer this question myself. I decided to NOT use a payout address for my p2pool command line, and only used dash core wallet reception addresses for my worker names, but each worker address is *address+difficultNumber*. It's working fine and reporting well in the p2pool web page, whereas it wasn't reporting things before using the above initial scheme. It looks like this arrangement will be more profitable than the previous one too.